# postfix on the cloud without mydomain

Tags: docker, postfix

I'm trying to make postfix server on a cluster (docker swarm). The postfix main.cf configuration needs mydomain but I'm not using a dedicated machine to domain name.

I have 10 machines and 6 domains. (a.com, b.com, c.com...) Every machine has 2 docker swarm services with all domains.

I'm not using reverse proxy (like nginx). Every domain has 10 IP addresses. When a client requests a domain, the response can be of any machine (IP).

The postfix seems to have a 90s mentality, where a single IP address maches a single domain and vice versa.

How can I config postfix without mydomain option? (Like apache virtual domain. Multiple machines, multiple domains).

I known postfix works with virtual mailbox domains but I need it without mydomain, only virtual domains, and postfix wants myorigin, mydomain, mydestination, but the server instance lives on 10 machines at the same time.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting `mydestination = localhost` and leave `myorigin`, `mydomain` as default.

Providing that you otherwise properly setup your Postfix to handle mail for virtual domains (a.com, b.com, c.com), the `myorigin`, `mydomain` and `mydestination` will not interfere with mail delivery for the virtual domains.

**Edit**

> What about the PTR records and virtual domains?

This won't be an issue.

What matters is that the server has `PTR` record *in the DNS system* and that it matches the `A` record. Also, ensure that the [SPF record](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sender_Policy_Framework) is set correctly for your domains (also in DNS system).

Comment: What about the PTR records and virtual domains? Many servers verify the PTR record (IP address and domain) to avoid spam. Email protocols are primitive, it need an urgent change.

Comment: No. Most of them verify that the server _has_ a PTR record (and, often, that it matches the EHLO). They **do not** verify that the PTR matches the message sender. Do you think Outlook365 or GSuite or hundreds of small webhosting providers still allocate a separate IP address for each email domain they host? **No they don't.** They have one cluster of servers, with **one** PTR record each, which handles hundreds of domains without issues.

Comment: @eduardkr, user1686 is right, see my edit.

Comment: okay, thank you. But I don't understand. Eeach domain has 10 A records (one per IP). Each domain has a single PTR record but what IP address? (any IP of the 10 nodes)

Comment: @eduardkr, _"Each domain has a single PTR record"_. PTR record is not a property of a domain. PTR records exist for **IP-addresses**, not for domains. DNS `A` entry resolves a hostname into IP-address. DNS `PTR` record is the opposite - it resolves an IP-address into a hostname. So, if your domain is hosted by 10 servers with unique IP addresses, then there will be 10 `A` entries and 10 `PTR` entries in DNS system for those 10 hosts.

Comment: @eduardkr, If you have 10 `A` entries for a single hostname that resolve into 10 different IP-addresses, then you can set `PTR` entries for these IP-addresses to resolve into that hostname.

Comment: Of course but an IP address only have a single PTR record. (one per IPv4 and one per IPv6). I can't add more than one.

Comment: @eduardkr, Why do you need more than one PTR record? There is no rule that mail servers that handle mail for a particular domain need to have an `A` or `PTR` record within this domain. `mail.example.com` can handle mail for `a.com`, `b.com`, etc without problems. This is where `SPF` records come in to help indicate that a particular server is authorized to relay mail for certain domains.

Comment: Thank you very much. I'm testing it now. (4 days ago I'm testing. It's much work to do without any automated tool. Only command line).

Comment: Leaving mydomain by default the postfix esmtp is servername.localdomain and this is SPAM. What can I do? Some people says that if you have more than one domain you can choose any as local for the server. This is not my case.

Comment: postfix should response with the domain name of the client request instead a fixed domain name. And it should use the own domain certificate (for every domain its own certificate).